# Help for Air Canada Fare Calculation Example

Tags: air-canada

Could you please help to explain how the below air ticket fare break down?
 [image: Electronic ticket]

I see the XT tax $130.55, the fare calculation shows the break down, but it does not really match. As far as I know that ROE means rate of exchange, so 1.00 is the exchange rate.

However, if I sum up the rest of amount it is $129.90, and there is still a difference of $0.65.

[image: Highlights]

Comment: An exchange rate of 1.005 could be displayed as 1.00. This explains a 0.65 difference.

Comment: @ugoren there's no exchange calculation for which the rate could plausibly be 1.005.  The current rate between CAD and USD is 4/3.  Besides, the fare is explicitly quoted in CAD.

Comment: @phoog, The OP mentioned a 1.00 exchange rate. I really don't know  between what and what. Maybe CAD to CAD, and then 1.005 really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

The fare calculation should be as below. All in CA$
452.00 fare
30.00 SQ
12.10 CA
24.71 (not shown) XG (5%GST of the above 3)
5.27 XA
9.32 XY
7.32 YC
47.94 US
7.46 AY
5.99 XF

Sum:
602.11

XT in their calculation is SQ+XG+XA+XY+YC+US+XF (no CA and AY)
which comes to $130.55

The Passenger facility charge for IAH is shown in both CAD$5.99 and US$4.50 at the end.

Comment: Any idea why XG was omitted from the horizontal calculation?

Comment: @Calchas Only think I can think of is that it's a manual error. Why should that AY be shown in the taxes section instead of XG?